# Springboot dropdown menu - "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI" error

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a dropdown which consists of options retrieved from a method. The user should be able to select one of these options, and press a submit button. Upon pressing the submit button, the button executes a method that takes the selected option and stores it in some other variable.

Upon pressing submit however, it returns this error:

No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/sendTest] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'

My drop-down form looks like this currenty:

```
sb.append("<p>"
                + "<div style='height:200px;width:500px;border:1px solid #ccc;font:16px/26px Georgia, Garamond, Serif;overflow:auto;'>"

                + "<form action='/sendTest' method='get'>"

                + "<input type='submit' value='Submit' action='/sendTest' method='post'>"

                + "<a>Current Test for students: " + testcont.getActiveTest() + "</a>"

                + "<fieldset><p>"
                + "<label>Select test</label>"
                + "<select name = 'selection'>"
                + currentTestOptions() // input
                + "</select></p></fieldset>"
                + "</form>"
                + "</div>"
                + "</p>");
```

and the method the

```
<input type='submit' value='Submit' action='/sendTest' method='post'>"
```

button should execute is:

```
@PostMapping("/sendTest")
    @ResponseBody
    public void sendTest(@RequestParam(name = "selection") HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
                    throws IOException, ServletException{

        for(Test test : testcont.showAllTests()){
            if(test.getName().equals(request.getParameter("selection"))){
                testcont.SetActiveTest(test);
                System.out.println(testcont.getActiveTest());
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT: The whole controller class

```
package project.answers.teacher;

import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

import org.springframework.aop.target.ThreadLocalTargetSourceStats;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import junit.extensions.TestSetup;
import project.answers.customExceptions.MultiFileNameException;
import project.answers.customExceptions.MultiTestNameException;
import project.answers.tests.Test;
import project.answers.tests.TestController;

// Teacher webpage 

@MultipartConfig
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/Teacher", produces = "text/html;charset=UTF-8")
public class Teacher {
    TestController testcont = TestController.getInstance();

    @GetMapping("")
    @PostMapping("")
    @ResponseBody

    public String homePage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.append("<p> <a href='/Teacher/NewTest'>New Test upload</a></p>\n");

        sb.append("<p>"
                + "<div style='height:200px;width:500px;border:1px solid #ccc;font:16px/26px Georgia, Garamond, Serif;overflow:auto;'>"

                + "<form action='/sendTest' method='post'>"

                + "<input type='submit' value='Submit' action='/sendTest' method='post'>"

                + "<a>Current Test for students: " + testcont.getActiveTest() + "</a>"

                + "<fieldset><p>"
                + "<label>Select test</label>"
                + "<select name = 'selection'>"
                + currentTestOptions() // input
                + "</select></p></fieldset>"
                + "</form>"
                + "</div>"
                + "</p>");

        sb.append(
                "<p>All available tests on server:<div style='height:200px;width:400px;border:1px solid #ccc;font:16px/26px Georgia, Garamond, Serif;overflow:auto;'>"
                + availableTestList() + "</div></p>"
                );

        return sb.toString();
    }

    @PostMapping
    @RequestMapping("/NewTest")
    @ResponseBody
    public String newTestUpload(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        // irrelevant method
    }



    @PostMapping("/sendTest")
    @ResponseBody
    public String sendTest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
                    throws IOException, ServletException{

        for(Test test : testcont.showAllTests()){
            if(test.getName().equals(request.getParameter("selection"))){
                testcont.SetActiveTest(test);
                System.out.println(testcont.getActiveTest());
            }
        }
        return "<a href='/Teacher'>Back</a>";
    }

    @PostMapping("/resetCurrentTest")
    public void resetCurrentTest(){
        testcont.SetActiveTest(null);
    }


    public String currentTestOptions() {


        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for(Test test : testcont.showAllTests()){
            sb.append("<option value = '" + test.getName() + "'>" + test.getName() + " - " + test.getFile().getName() + "</option>");
        }

        return sb.toString();

    }

    public String availableTestList(){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for(Test test : testcont.showAllTests()){
            sb.append("<p>" + test.getName() + " - " + test.getFile().getName() +"</p>");
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's semply because you send your form to `[GET] /sendTest` but your spring controller is mapped on `[POST] /Teacher/sendTest`.

Change your html form to send as post :

```
sb.append("<p>"
                + "<div style='height:200px;width:500px;border:1px solid #ccc;font:16px/26px Georgia, Garamond, Serif;overflow:auto;'>"

                + "<form action='/Teacher/sendTest' method='POST'>"

                + "<input type='submit' value='Submit' action='/sendTest' method='post'>"

                + "<a>Current Test for students: " + testcont.getActiveTest() + "</a>"

                + "<fieldset><p>"
                + "<label>Select test</label>"
                + "<select name = 'selection'>"
                + currentTestOptions() // input
                + "</select></p></fieldset>"
                + "</form>"
                + "</div>"
                + "</p>");
```

Comment: Still gives me the same error :/

Thanks though, didn't see that one!

Comment: Can you edit question to add the whole controller class. I wand to verify that `@Controller` annotation is right

Comment: Ok so first you used `@RestController` but you're not doing rest. So change with `@Controller`.
Then your form post endPoint is mapped on `/Teacher/sendTest` so change it in your http form

Comment: Getting another error now, but that solved the mapping issue! Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need change your action value from `action='/sendTest'` to `action='/Teacher/sendTest'`